# Arrow keys jump more than one character

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

So i'm working in Eclipse. I probably press some random key combination and from then on my arrow keys work in a weird way. They jump to the end of the line instead of just one character.

It's so frustraing, been searching around for days now, with no luck.
Works fine after restarting the computer.
After i pressed the combination it happens everywhere. For example: in the superuser text editor.

Comment: ohh sorry, it's for example.

Comment: Does the issue persist after you restart?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a laptop or small keyboard, try tapping the **fn** key, or looking for another modifier button such as **num lock**. Toggling this will change it back to normal keyboard navigation.

If you have multiple languages installed, hit [windows]+[r] and type `osk` [enter]. Check to confirm the onscreen keyboard looks the same as yours.

---

Often US keyboards with less than 104 keys have a "function" key to overload the uses of each key. For example most laptops use smaller keyboards for strength reasons, so holding "fn" turns the arrow keys into **Page up/down**, **Home/End** to make up for the fact they don't have those keys normally.

A **Dead Key** is a modifier key which no longer needs to be held down. On some computers: this may be single-tapping "fn" once, and now the next button you press is the modified version *(so "up arrow" becomes "page up")*. On some models: if you press [CTRL]+[FN] it will stay on that modified version until you toggle it back off again.
 Sony laptops change function of about HALF THE KEYBOARD when **numlock** is *toggled* on

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Im using a desktop pc. Next time it happens i will check the osk.